# Haskell, sorting trios only by first field

Tags: haskell

I have a list of elements of `(Int, Int, Int)`.
How to sort this list only by first element ?
With pairs I can deal, but with three elements I have a problem

Comment: How do you do it with pairs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you defined a `fst`-like function for a tuple of size three:

```hs
fst3 :: (a, b, c) -> a
fst3 (a, _, _) = a
```

then you can use [`comparing`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Ord.html#v:comparing):

```hs
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

sortByFst3 :: Ord a => [(a, b, c)] -> [(a, b, c)]
sortByFst3 = sortBy (comparing fst3)
```

Comment: Side comment (maybe just musing): defining functions like `fst3`, `fst4`, `snd3`, etc always struck me as not-scalable. I'd recommend just using `sortBy (comparing (\(a, _, _) -> a))`. That said, a [quick search](https://www.stackage.org/lts-7.15/hoogle?q=%28a%2Cb%2Cc%29+-%3E+a) reveals that a _bunch_ of packages redefine this function. I can't help wondering which is worse: having things like `fst3` in the Prelude, or having a bunch of equivalent functions sprinkled across various package? Oh well...

Comment: The only thing `fst3` gets you is stable ordering when the first elements are identical. The default ordering for 3-tuples already sorts for `a` first, then `b` when necessary, and finally `c` if necessary.

Comment: @chepner It also gets you the ability to sort things where the second or third elements don't support Ord.

Answer (score 0):

Since [base](https://www.stackage.org/package/base) 4.8.0, there is Data.List.[sortOn](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.15/base-4.9.0.0/Data-List.html#v:sortOn)

```
import Data.List

lst = [(3,1,2), (2,1,3), (1,3,2)]

main = do
  let srt = sortOn (\(a,_,_) -> a) lst
  print $ srt
```

yield

```
[(1,3,2),(2,1,3),(3,1,2)]
```